# Custom domain gitlab pages

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

I have hosted a website with gitlab pages which I can access at [gpecchio.gitlab.io/BeCall](http://gpecchio.gitlab.io/BeCall).
However, I also bought the domain [becall.io](http://www.becall.io) and I wanted to use this domain and not the gitlab one. I tried to follow the documentation but I can't quite figure out what to put in my `CNAME` record as `host` and as `value`. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your A record should be:

**name:** becall.io , **value:** 52.167.214.135

Your CNAME might be:

**name:** www, **value:**  becall.io